# Visual Basic MsgBox not showing After progress bar is Finished

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a bingo card in Visual Basic!

But there is one problem, whenever the progress bar finishes it does not show a MsgBox!

My code is down below ⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣

```
    Public Class ScamBingo
    Private Sub ScamBingo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Interval = 100
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
        ProgressBar1.Step = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(15.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button8.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            MsgBox("hi")
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button5.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button4.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button6.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button7.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button3.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

So if anyone can help, that would be great, thanks :)

Extra info:

I use buttons to make the progress bar go up!
I am fairly new to Visual Basic!

Comment: is it VBA or is it VB ... it cannot be both ... please correct your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timer1`already stop in all the button clicks.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()
    Timer1.Stop()
    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

It is the reason why the timer1 is unable to call `Timer1_Tick` .

Try this when the progress bar hit its maximum value that is the time we stop the timer, then show MsgBox:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Interval = 100
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 40
    ProgressBar1.Step = 1

End Sub



Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(15.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button2.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button8.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        MsgBox("hi")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button5.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button4.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button6.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button7.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(12.5)
    Timer1.Start()

    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub End Class
```